# How to create has_one association in simple-form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

In many-to-many association, If we have

```
class Video
  has_many :tagging
  has_many :tags, through: :tagging
end

class Tagging
  belongs_to :video
  belongs_to :tag

class Tag
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :videos, through: :tagging
```

I can use `f.association :tags, as: :check_boxes` to create the association which can create a instance in Tagging with `video_id` and `tag_id`

But, I want to change to the video `has_one` tagging. But I cannot create the association because the `simple-form` don't support has_one association.

```
class Video
  has_one :tagging
  has_one :tag, through: :tagging
end
```

What should I do? If I want to create the association instance in `tagging` when I create a video and select a tag?

Comment: Then don't use simple-form.. what is wrong with doing the ordinary way?

Comment: @ilanberci What's the ordinary way? I didn't find any tutorial for this. Is that using `field for`?